# quandl api for matlab and matlab serial date number (datenum)

Tags: matlab, date, serial-port, time-series, quandl

I had a doubt using the Quandl API for MATLAB:
When I get the data using the Quandl.get function, for example:

```
startDate = {'2013-12-20'}; % initial date 
endDate = {'2014-10-21'}; % final date
data = Quandl.get('OFDP/FUTURE_CL1', 'trim_start', startDate, 'trim_end',  endDate);
```

I can access the field data.Settle.Data to get the prices 
and data.Settle.Time to get the time date (perhaps a Time format of timeseries from MATLAB).

The problem is the following: in 
`dates = data.Settle.Time`,
I get a date format that isn't compatible with MATLAB date. For example, if use `datestr(dates)` the corresponding string date isn't the actual date when I download the data manually.

I also tried to transform the dates vector manually using 
`datenum(startDate) + dates`.

But it didn't work at all.

I would like to know how can I solve this (perhaps little) problem in order to get the real MATLAB serial date (like datenum(2014,10,21)).

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

datenum(getabstime(data)) should do the trick.